# an optimised way to change labels colors each 10 ms

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to change a set of labels (8 X 8) background color upon event triggering each 10 ms, I'm using a thread `CreateThread(NULL, 0, colorLabel, NULL, 0, 0);` called each 10ms

```
DWORD WINAPI colorLabel(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if (hBrushLabel) {
                DeleteObject(hBrushLabel);
                hBrushLabel = NULL;
            }
            clrLabelBkGnd = RGB((i * 4) % 255, (j * 4) % 255, 0x00);
            InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[i][j], NULL, TRUE);
        }
    }
    colored = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

CALLBACK program:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
         hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
        SetTextColor(hdc, clrLabelText);
        SetBkColor(hdc, clrLabelBkGnd);
        if (!hBrushLabel) hBrushLabel = CreateSolidBrush(clrLabelBkGnd);
        return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(hBrushLabel);
```

but this method is too heavy, the display is destroyed

is there any optimized way to change labels color display each 10ms

Comment: Create your brushes ahead of time (in `WM_CREATE` or even in `main()`). Use `WM_TIMER` to switch which brush is returned from `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Maybe you want to paint rectangles and draw text using `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: That would be better; I'm not sure what the labels are going to be used for so I was going to suggest that if what I originally said doesn't help :/ Threads are definitely not going to help though, especially given the code in the OP, which is wrong (it disobeys thread affinity rules for windows).

Comment: The windowing subsystem isn't optimized to render 100 frames per second. You may want to look into a more direct way of manipulating screen contents, e.g. [Direct2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990.aspx) or [Direct3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309466.aspx).

Comment: You can declare a big array of HBRUSH objects, and each time you create a brush, assign it's handle to the next position in the array. Keep a counter of the number of brushes created, then when it reaches a certain number, delete all brushes in the array  at once. That way you don't have to call `DeleteObject()` each time in the loop. If the number of brushes is not too large, you can delete them when the program ends

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *Many older computers may not handle 10 millisecond delay with this method. Minimum 30 millisecond delay is better, or go a bit higher. Also this is not for gaming, it's for light weight animation in non-gaming program*

Edit 2: *changed how `GetDC` is called*

Another option is to draw a rectangle and text, then `Sleep` for 10 miliseconds. The actual painting might take several milliseconds, in that case use `QueryPerformanceCounter` to sleep for less than 10 milliseconds. Note that these changes won't be saved unless something is done in `WM_PAINT` too.

```
DWORD WINAPI foo(LPVOID p)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)p;
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency, clock1, clock2;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    wchar_t buf[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&clock1);
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);//release hdc as soon as possible
        wsprintf(buf, L"%i\n", i);
        RECT rc = {0,0,50,20};
        COLORREF bkcolor = RGB(128, 255, 255);
        HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(bkcolor);
        SetBkColor(hdc, bkcolor);
        FillRect(hdc, &rc, brush);
        DeleteObject(brush); 
        TextOut(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, buf, lstrlen(buf));
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&clock2);
        int delay = int(((clock2.QuadPart - clock1.QuadPart) * 1000) / frequency.QuadPart);
        if (delay < 10)
            Sleep(10 - delay); //10 millisecond delay
    }
    return 123;
}    
...
CreateThread(NULL, 0, foo, hwnd, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: When updating the contents of a window from a thread, other than the owning thread, the outcome is undefined. Don't do that. Your assumptions about `Sleep` are off, too: You suggest, that `Sleep` will expire precisely after the amount specified. That is not the case. The thread can be scheduled run (significantly) later. Or earlier, if the argument is less than the system clock resolution. 10 milliseconds may well be below the supported minimum already.

Comment: @IInspectable The first point is obvious, I mentioned already that `WM_PAINT` will do its own thing, there are other issues and it can be dealt with. I don't understand your comment "Don't do it". I edited the answer, trying to address the second point you brought up.

Comment: You are calling `GetDC` from a thread, that is not the owner of the window, and then render to it. This is outside the specification: You can only modify a window (and the resources it owns) from the thread that created it. Irrespective of that, `Sleep`-based animations are generally jerky and unpleasant. The common solution is to render as fast as possible, and render the contents based on the current timestamp. I don't see, how your edit addressed the second point I brought up, either. The thread still sleeps an unpredictable amount of time.

Comment: @IInspectable The non-message thread can use `GetDC` as long as it's not being used by another thread. `Sleep` is not totally unpredictable. I tested the above code with 15 year old single-core laptop, it works fine.

Comment: And how do you propose to prevent the owning thread from using the device context, while the rogue thread is using it? Your code certainly didn't implement any sort of coordination, and since you are presumably dealing with a standard control, you cannot go in and change that, to implement any sort of orchestration. As for the smoke test with an old, single-core machine: Those machines generally exhibit a lot more predictability than current multi-core devices.

Comment: If there is a lot of rendering then each pass takes longer than 10 milliseconds, or longer than 30 milliseconds. You can't do anything about that. If the computer is busy with something else then it will be slow. Any other method will have the same problem ----- If `hdc` is released quickly then there is no problem. In a more extreme case, different processes can call `GetDC(NULL)`, maybe it's not a good idea but it's not illegal.

Comment: A solution that works as expected, **if you're lucky**, is not generally accepted as a solution. Windows have thread affinity, like all USER objects. While the window manager tries its best to ensure thread safety, there is no provision for synchronization, and the result of accessing a device context from multiple threads is unpredictable. Plus, `Sleep` doesn't provide the guarantees you are relying on. This is not a solution, and I downvoted the answer to communicate as much.